# Generate JWT for Apple Music API with online editor

Tags: ios, swift

I read the full documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/SetUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH2-SW1.

I generated JWT with kid,iss , iat exp. But when I hit apple music api

with

`"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Iko4UTJNTFA5RjMifQ.eyJpYXQiOjE1MTE0Mzc5ODgsImV4cCI6MTUxNjcwODM4OCwiaXNzIjoiN0Y0Ujk4WDRNVCJ9.iPFxiHc475spn2AVmO8-Q2bGOM_Rz5OqhAb-sMQ2cXQlGcbx6pfZaTpjI0r6vAaQnqeoFb8fNvVobjtiC2eyzw"` header authorization.

API is https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/search?term=khalid&types=albums

I am getting the following response header

```
{ URL: https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/search?term=khalid&types=albums } { status code: 401, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Fri, 24 Nov 2017 09:21:29 GMT";
} })
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that your token is not valid or is expired. See https://github.com/klaas/SwiftJWTSample for an example.